# php form: prevent outside posters with tokens

Tags: php, webforms, security

I'm making a web game for fun with lots of forms that post data to php pages. What are some methods to preventing people from using their own web forms to post to my site?

My knowledge PHP is not too advanced. So, while I've been researching this topic, unfortunately the answers I've found have been confusing me a little. I found this SO question from earlier that addressed the issue: [Secure ajax form POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888979/secure-ajax-form-post). I'm a little confused by the first answer and was wondering if somebody could provide an example in PHP. Some specific points I'm struggling with are:

- how would you save a token somewhere on your server?
- how do you decide what that token should be?
- if somebody is on the website, can't they just view the source and
  see the token in the hidden input element and use that in their own
  third party form?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of CSRF prevention libraries you can use. One is [CSRFGuard at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_CSRFGuard_Project)

You may also wish to read the [main CSRF page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)  to understand the issues and the [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)  to understand the principles behind the implementation design.

If you've read up and understood the issues, it should be a simple job to add your own protection, if you wish to construct your own implementation.

Bear in mind that if you have any [XSS vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS), your CSRF protection can be simply bypassed. So be sure to understand [XSS Prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) also.

Comment: Thanks, Cheekysoft. I'll read through those links. I think I understand how it works now, but I'm just unsure how to implement it. Reading through the source code of the protection libraries at OWASP should help, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. The token is stored in the user's session along with an expiration date/time
2. The token can be generated automatically, per-user. It needs to be random enough to avoid guessing.
3. Yes, but you can combat this by using per-user token generation and expiration. If a token is submitted without an existing user session, or if the token has expired in the current session, redirect the user to an appropriate notification of failure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, George. I'm still not quite understanding the token method. So, would you perhaps store variables like $_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['expirationTime'], and so on? As for the 3rd part, why can't the person just write a php file locally and set the session variables themselves and submit the form? I think I'm still missing something fundamental about this  method. I was hoping to find a simple example of it coded in PHP, but I haven't been able to find one online.

Comment: @navr91: This is small example for you:
`$_SESSION['token'] = md5(time());`
`$_SESSION['expire'] = time() + 30; //30 seconds`
when show the form:
`<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['token']?>"` />

When you get the POST data, compare them:
`If ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['expire']) //expired`

You should implement this more to use with many forms (multi-token)